# Observed velocity of radially infalling particle into a Schwarzschild black hole

Tags: general-relativity

I have a black hole, and a stationary observer next to it at some fixed radius. I have a particle which falls into the black hole from rest.

I know how to calculate the energy of the infalling particle seen by the observer, when it is passing by:

$$g_{\mu \nu} u^{\mu} p^{\nu}$$

where $g_{\mu \nu}$ is the metric where the observer and infalling particle meets, $u$ is the 4-velocity of the observer, $p$ is the 4-momentum of the infalling particle.

How do I translate this to velocity though? What is the observed velocity of the infalling particle when it passes by the observer?

(I also know the coordinate velocity at some $r$ value, that is not what I am asking for.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how to calculate the energy as seen in the observers frame, then $E = \gamma mc^2$. Hence $v$